# Install vim from source fails

Tags: installing

### Download vim using git

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
Cloning into 'vim'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 135556, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (370/370), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (182/182), done.
remote: Total 135556 (delta 225), reused 301 (delta 184), pack-reused 135186
Receiving objects: 100% (135556/135556), 117.30 MiB | 955.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (114799/114799), done.
```

### Install

```
cd vim/src
make
```

### Output

```
root@f0833a7cb391:~# cd vim/src/
root@f0833a7cb391:~/vim/src# make
Makefile:304: auto/config.mk: No such file or directory
rm -f auto/config.cache
if test "X" != "Xclean" \
    -a "X" != "Xdistclean" \
    -a "X" != "Xautoconf" \
    -a "X" != "Xreconfig"; then \
    GUI_INC_LOC="" GUI_LIB_LOC="" \
    CC="" CPPFLAGS="" CFLAGS="" \
    LDFLAGS=""  srcdir="." \
    ./configure    \
       \
       \
       \
       \
      \
      \
       \
      \
        \
       \
      \
      \
     ; \
fi
configure: creating cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for strip... strip
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for unsigned long long int... yes
checking for long long int... yes
checking if the compiler supports trailing commas... yes
checking if the compiler supports C++ comments... yes
checking --enable-fail-if-missing argument... no
checking for clang version... N/A
configure: checking for buggy tools...
checking for Haiku... no
checking for QNX... no
checking for Darwin (Mac OS X)... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking AvailabilityMacros.h usability... no
checking AvailabilityMacros.h presence... no
checking for AvailabilityMacros.h... no
checking --with-local-dir argument... Defaulting to /usr/local
checking --with-vim-name argument... Defaulting to vim
checking --with-ex-name argument... Defaulting to ex
checking --with-view-name argument... Defaulting to view
checking --with-global-runtime argument... no
checking --with-modified-by argument... no
checking if character set is EBCDIC... no
checking --disable-smack argument... no
checking linux/xattr.h usability... yes
checking linux/xattr.h presence... yes
checking for linux/xattr.h... yes
checking attr/xattr.h usability... no
checking attr/xattr.h presence... no
checking for attr/xattr.h... no
checking --disable-selinux argument... no
checking for is_selinux_enabled in -lselinux... no
checking --with-features argument... Defaulting to huge
checking --with-compiledby argument... no
checking --disable-xsmp argument... no
checking --disable-xsmp-interact argument... no
checking --enable-luainterp argument... no
checking --enable-mzschemeinterp argument... no
checking --enable-perlinterp argument... no
checking --enable-pythoninterp argument... no
checking --enable-python3interp argument... no
checking --enable-tclinterp argument... no
checking --enable-rubyinterp argument... no
checking --enable-cscope argument... no
checking --disable-netbeans argument... no
checking --disable-channel argument... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking whether compiling with IPv6 networking is possible... yes
checking for inet_ntop... yes
checking --enable-terminal argument... defaulting to yes
checking --enable-autoservername argument... no
checking --enable-multibyte argument... yes
checking --disable-rightleft argument... no
checking --disable-arabic argument... no
checking --enable-xim argument... defaulting to auto
checking --enable-fontset argument... no
checking for xmkmf... no
checking for X... libraries , headers
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking if X11 header files can be found... yes
checking for _XdmcpAuthDoIt in -lXdmcp... yes
checking for IceOpenConnection in -lICE... yes
checking for XpmCreatePixmapFromData in -lXpm... no
checking if X11 header files implicitly declare return values... no
checking size of wchar_t is 2 bytes... no
checking --enable-gui argument... yes/auto - automatic GUI support
checking whether or not to look for GTK+ 2... yes
checking whether or not to look for GNOME... no
checking whether or not to look for GTK+ 3... yes
checking whether or not to look for Motif... yes
checking whether or not to look for Athena... yes
checking whether or not to look for neXtaw... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled
checking for GTK -dev package... no
checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled
checking for GTK -dev package... no
checking for location of Motif GUI includes... <not found>
checking if Athena header files can be found... no
checking if neXtaw header files can be found... no
checking X11/SM/SMlib.h usability... yes
checking X11/SM/SMlib.h presence... yes
checking for X11/SM/SMlib.h... yes
checking X11/xpm.h usability... no
checking X11/xpm.h presence... no
checking for X11/xpm.h... no
checking X11/Sunkeysym.h usability... yes
checking X11/Sunkeysym.h presence... yes
checking for X11/Sunkeysym.h... yes
checking for XIMText in X11/Xlib.h... yes
checking for /proc link to executable... /proc/self/exe
checking for CYGWIN or MSYS environment... no
checking whether toupper is broken... no
checking whether __DATE__ and __TIME__ work... yes
checking whether __attribute__((unused)) is allowed... yes
checking elf.h usability... yes
checking elf.h presence... yes
checking for elf.h... yes
checking for main in -lelf... no
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking termcap.h usability... no
checking termcap.h presence... no
checking for termcap.h... no
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking sgtty.h usability... yes
checking sgtty.h presence... yes
checking for sgtty.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking termio.h usability... yes
checking termio.h presence... yes
checking for termio.h... yes
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking math.h usability... yes
checking math.h presence... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking stropts.h usability... yes
checking stropts.h presence... yes
checking for stropts.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking sys/systeminfo.h usability... no
checking sys/systeminfo.h presence... no
checking for sys/systeminfo.h... no
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking sys/stream.h usability... no
checking sys/stream.h presence... no
checking for sys/stream.h... no
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking libc.h usability... no
checking libc.h presence... no
checking for libc.h... no
checking sys/statfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statfs.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking sys/poll.h usability... yes
checking sys/poll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking pwd.h usability... yes
checking pwd.h presence... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/ptms.h usability... no
checking sys/ptms.h presence... no
checking for sys/ptms.h... no
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking libgen.h usability... yes
checking libgen.h presence... yes
checking for libgen.h... yes
checking util/debug.h usability... no
checking util/debug.h presence... no
checking for util/debug.h... no
checking util/msg18n.h usability... no
checking util/msg18n.h presence... no
checking for util/msg18n.h... no
checking frame.h usability... no
checking frame.h presence... no
checking for frame.h... no
checking sys/acl.h usability... no
checking sys/acl.h presence... no
checking for sys/acl.h... no
checking sys/access.h usability... no
checking sys/access.h presence... no
checking for sys/access.h... no
checking sys/sysinfo.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking wctype.h usability... yes
checking wctype.h presence... yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking for sys/ptem.h... no
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking for pthread_np.h... no
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking if strings.h can be included after string.h... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for ino_t... yes
checking for dev_t... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for inline... inline
checking for rlim_t... yes
checking for stack_t... yes
checking whether stack_t has an ss_base field... no
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      On Linux that would be the libncurses-dev package.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
Makefile:2069: recipe for target 'auto/config.mk' failed
make: *** [auto/config.mk] Error 1
```

Comment: What is the distro? On debian I build with this https://gist.github.com/habamax/687d1c7e8424066ecd3673e0f18f664f

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the ncurses (libncurses-dev) development
package (as the error message at the end states). If you
are using a Ubuntu system, you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt install libncurses-dev
```

Comment: I am inside a docker ... # apt install libncurses-dev //
Reading package lists... Done //
Building dependency tree //
Reading state information... Done //
E: Unable to locate package libncurses-dev

Comment: Containers !== virtual machines. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should check `src/auto/config.log` for relevant message, as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/3zR-hLaGIFA)

Recently build vim from source on cygwin failed with `checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!`, it cannot find ncurses when `libncurses-devel` already installed.

In my case, `./configure` use `/usr/local/lib` which is empty, after add `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"`, then works successfully. [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146370/cygwin-vim-configure-missing-terminal-library-for-example-ncurses/76174741#76174741)